# How to send data from table row to post api

Tags: html, reactjs, api, frontend

I have a table in React.

```
<Table>
     <tr>
     <td><TextField/></td>
</Table>
<Button onClick={(e)=> submit()}> SUBMIT </Button>
```

Now i want to send the input of the textField to a post api call when i click the submit button.

```
const submit = () => {
asyncPost(url, data_to_be_sent).then((response) => {console.log(“ok”)})
```

I need to send the value i enter in the textfield to the asyncPost. How should i do that?

Comment: Check out my answer, it should help you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use hooks (if you use functional component) to be able to store value from `<TextField/>` inside it. Later you can use it when clicking on a button. You can find an example [here](https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

You create hook by:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(null)
```

The difference is that you will use `onChange` event on `<TextField/>` like:

```
<TextField onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)} />
```

so later you can use it like:

```
const submit = () => {
asyncPost(url, inputValue).then((response) => {console.log(“ok”)})
```

Comment: One small follow up question. If I have <td> {props.data.map((p)=> <div><TextField/>}</td> then how do I get all the data of all the TextFields?